# Cannot Increase open file limit past 4096 (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ulimit, ubuntu-17.04

I'm on Ubuntu 17.04. Trying to increase the open file limit, and none of the instructions I've found online are working. I can go up to 4096, but can't go past that.

```
$ ulimit -n
1024
$ ulimit -n 4096
$ ulimit -n
4096
```

That works. This doesn't:

```
$ ulimit -n 4097
bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

It appears to be because of the hard limit:

```
$ ulimit -Hn
4096
```

I've tried adding these lines to /etc/security/limits.conf:

```
*                hard    nofile          65535
*                soft    nofile          65535
root             soft    nofile          65535
root             hard    nofile          65535
```

Also added this line to /etc/pam.d/common-session and /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive:

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

Since doing that, I've rebooted my computer. Changes to limits.conf don't seem to affect anything. The hard limit is still stuck at 4096, preventing me from going any higher. **How do I increase my open files limit?**

---

Here's some additional config info:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max 
1624668
```

Answer (score 115, accepted):

OK, I finally figured this out. The limits I was setting in `/etc/security/limits.conf` were indeed being applied, but not to the **graphical login**. This can be verified from a terminal window:

```
$ ulimit -n
4096
$ su mkasberg
Password:
$ ulimit -n
65535
```

More research led me to this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1627769), which got me pointed in the right direction. In order to modify the limit that is used by the login shell, we need to add the following line to `/etc/systemd/user.conf`:

```
DefaultLimitNOFILE=65535
```

That change works, but only affecting the soft limit. (Leaving us capped with a hard limit of 4096 still.) In order to affect the hard limit, we must modify `/etc/systemd/system.conf` with the same changes.

The changes I made in `/etc/pam.d` were not necessarily; it's already working, at least on Ubuntu. Also, it was not necessary to add the lines `root` and `*` in `limits.conf`; adding the username alone (`mkasberg` in my case) was sufficient.

---

### In Summary

If you want to increase the limit shown by `ulimit -n`, you should:

- Modify `/etc/systemd/user.conf` and `/etc/systemd/system.conf` with the following line (this takes care of graphical login):

  ```
   DefaultLimitNOFILE=65535
  ```
- Modify `/etc/security/limits.conf` with the following lines (this takes care of non-GUI login):

  ```
   mkasberg hard nofile 65535
   mkasberg soft nofile 65535
  ```
- Reboot your computer for changes to take effect.

Comment: `DefaultLimitNOFILE=65535` did the trick. But why `/etc/security/limits.conf ` does'nt work?

Comment: The GUI login uses systemd, which apparently has it's own configuration (`/etc/systemd/system.conf`) that is independent of the normal configuration for terminal sessions (`/etc/security/limits.conf`). I don't know enough about systemd to know why it was implemented this way.

Comment: Thank you!  Hours of searching and trying everything, but this fixed the issue.

Comment: @Suvitruf because it's ignored in a *systemd* system. I'm posting an answer.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Still stuck to `1024`.

Comment: I could change the value by first `su <username>` and _then_ using `ulimit -n 5000`. I guess it only changed for the current session.

Comment: Just want to point out that limits for `root` user can't be specified by `*` or group specifiers. `root` literal must be specified explicitly.

Comment: This works for me, after a **reboot**.

Comment: Soon, we'll have a monolithic system, all of which will be systemd. /s

Comment: After struggling for a day, this is the only solution that worked for me! Cheers.

Comment: Just logout and login again, on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: As mentioned by @MatthewMa a safer option if you want to adjust the limit for a _specific process_ - would be to add a `LimitNOFILE=` to the respective _systemd unit file_ directly

Comment: works on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: This did not work for me on Fedora 34. I'm still stuck at 64 even after editing all of these files and the ones supposedly ignored. Restarted multiple times. Still only showing ulimit -l # 64

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me on Centos 7.2; thank you!

Comment: This worked for me. thanks a lot. Make sure to change all 3 mentioned files in the summary.

Answer (score 21):

No need to change anything in the `/etc/security/limits.conf` file, it is ignored if you are using systemd.

*(reproducing a modified [answer to another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/443467/154671) on the network...)*

An alternative for those who prefer not to edit the default `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and `/etc/systemd/user/conf` files:

1. create a new file `/etc/systemd/system.conf.d/limits.conf` with these contents:

   ```
   [Manager]
   DefaultLimitNOFILE=65535
   ```
2. run `systemctl daemon-reexec` as root
3. logout and login again
4. check your new limit with `ulimit -n`.

Refer to the [`systemd-system.conf` manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-system.conf.html) for details.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 18.10 system the file in question is at `/etc/systemd/system.conf`. Making the change there appears to have done the trick, thank you.

Comment: Just logging out for me did not work (Ubuntu 18.04) but restarting did the job. Very elegant solution, thanks.

Comment: Contrary to your claim, `limits.conf` is still loaded by `pam_limits.so`. `systemd` overrides `DefaultLimitNOFILE` regardless, as stated in its man page.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  @mkasberg's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR 
I felt the need to concentrate the answers, so they're easier to find.
Took me ages to get all the pieces together to make it work correctly ...

There are 2 locations to be considered.

1. **GUI session**

   ```
   $ grep DefaultLimitNOFILE /etc/systemd/system.conf
   DefaultLimitNOFILE=65535
   ```

   or better here:

   ```
   $ grep NOFILE /etc/systemd/system.conf.d/limits.conf
   DefaultLimitNOFILE=65535
   ```
2. **shell environment**

   ```
   $ grep nofile /etc/security/limits.conf
   user soft nofile 65535
   user hard nofile 65535`
   ```

   or better here:

   ```
   $ grep nofile /etc/security/limits.d/user.conf
   user soft nofile 65535
   user hard nofile 65535
   ```
3. After altering the settings in the above files, **reboot** and then check the limits with:
   `ulimit -n -Hn  -Sn`

Answer (score 3):

1. edit /etc/systemd/system/sonar.service
2. add these two line under Service

[Service]

LimitMEMLOCK=infinity

LimitNOFILE=65535

3. systemctl daemon-reload
4. systemctl restart sonar

this works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using Ubuntu 17.04 I got the described hard limit:

```
user@paresh.com:~$ ulimit -Hn
4096
```

I could lower it using `ulimit`, but not increase it, just as the question describes it. `ulimit` manual describes:

> only root can increase the hard limit.

So I tried to set a higher limit in `/etc/security/limits.conf` like this:

```
user hard nofile 9999
```

and a fresh login like `ssh localhost -l user` gave me the new limit:

```
user@paresh.com:~$ ulimit -Hn
9999
```

I hope this works for you too.